# CSS is different between two computers

Tags: css, reactjs, npm, postcss

A friend and I are building an application together. We both run the same project that is cloned from the same github page but get different results with the CSS.

The CSS that behaves differently:

```
#container {
  lost-center:90%;
}


@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Light', sans-serif;
  font-path: '../assets/fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Light';
}
```

Our npm packets; lost-grid, rucksack-css (for fonts)

His setup:
HP, Windows, Google Chrome
My setup: 
MacBook, OS, Google Chrome

The problem occurs on my computer; 
lost-center doesn't work at all, i.e lost-center: 100%

And the font doesn't work. In the element inspector it says 'Open Sans Light', but renders as more of a Times New Roman.

What can be wrong? 
Thanks!

Comment: Did you run `npm install` on your MacBook? Also look in Chrome's DevTools if a request was made for `OpenSans-Light` that failed with a `404`

Comment: this should do it [Apple discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7027302?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: Where are you coming up with a `lost-center` CSS property? There is no such thing.

Comment: As far as I could see, it's part of this `lost-grid` PostCSS package